# How to fine-tune transformers NLU model with dataset without labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, model, huggingface-transformers

I am using transformers model:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sberbank-ai/sbert_large_nlu_ru")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("sberbank-ai/sbert_large_nlu_ru")
```

Now, to get embeddings of words with this model. But I want to fine tune this model with my specific dataset which is unlabelled. How to do that? I saw this article https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training but data there is labeled

Comment: Finetune for which task?

Comment: @cronoik getting embeddings. nlu basically

Comment: You can follow this [guide](https://www.sbert.net/examples/domain_adaptation/README.html).

Comment: @cronoik its not python, i want to do it with Python

Comment: It is python...

Comment: @cronoik yeah but its about sentence_transformers library, not regular transformers one

Comment: First of all, the approach is the same (i.e. just copy the scripts and remove the sentence_transformers with hf transformers. Secondly, the sentence_transformers lib is a wrapper around hf transformers. It is always possible to extract the hf transformer and use it solely with hf and get the same results.

Comment: @cronoik thx, but i still don't understand how these methods could be applied to my bert model, if it was trained with natural language inference method and those in this article are, as good as i understand, trained with MLM method.